# i have json string in my dataframe i already tried to exract json sting columns using pyspark

Tags: pyspark

df = spark.read.json("dbfs:/mnt/evbhaent2blobs", multiLine=True)

## df2 = df.select(F.col('body').cast("Struct").getItem('CustomerType').alias('CustomerType'))

display(df)

my df is

[my oupputdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKgMN.png)

Comment: What is your question? The post isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

I am taking a guess that your dataframe has a column "body" which is a json string and you want to parse the json and extract an element from it.

First you need to define or extract the json schema. And then parse json string and extract its elements as column. From the extracted columns, you can select the desired columns.

```
json_schema = spark.read.json(df.rdd.map(lambda row: row.body)).schema
df2 = df.withColumn('body_json', F.from_json(F.col('body'), json_schema))\
        .select("body_json.*").select('CustomerType')

display(df2)
```